# Django models and relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've inherited a database that has undergone a redesign which includes adding foreign key and unique constraints.  Therefore, the previous tests are not valid for these models, and I'm rewriting the unit tests.

I have two classes in my `models.py` file:

```
class Parentorgs(models.Model):
  parentorg_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  parentorg = models.CharField(max_length=100L, db_column='ParentOrg', unique = True)
  eff_date = models.DateField()
  exp_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  class Meta:
    db_table = 'txn_parentorgs'

class Contracts(models.Model):
  parentorg_id = models.ForeignKey(Parentorgs)
  contractnum = models.CharField(max_length=10L, db_column='ContractNum', primary_key = True)
  eff_date = models.DateField()
  exp_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  contractname = models.CharField(max_length=100L, db_column='ContractName') # Field name made lowercase.
  class Meta:
    db_table = 'txn_contracts'
```

How can I create objects to be used for unit testing in the setup method?  I've tried

```
self.parentOrg = Parentorgs.objects.create(parentorg_id = 300, 
    parentorg = "TestParentOrgOne", eff_date = timezone.now(), exp_date = None)
self.contracts = Contracts.objects.create(parentorg_id = self.parentOrg, 
    contractnum = "1234", eff_date = timezone.now(), exp_date = None, 
    contractname = "testContractName")
```

This gives me an error when creating the `contracts` object, as I get an `unknown column 'parentorg_id_id' in field list` error.

How can I create a `parentOrg` and `contracts` objects with the appropriate relationship here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ForeignKey` is a relationship field and will automatically map the id, so your model should look like:

```
class Contracts(models.Model):
  parentorg = models.ForeignKey(Parentorgs)
  ...
```

And the relationship is created like so:

```
 Contracts.objects.create(parentorg = self.parentOrg, ...)
```

That will set the column `parentorg_id` to the `id` of `self.parentOrg`.

A couple of other, perhaps irrelevant, comments about the code:

- Model class names are usually singular, ie `Contact` instead of `Contracts`, since an instance is *one* contract.
- You don't need to set a primarily key manually - unless you really want to control how the primary key is used, the `parentorg_id` field in `Parentorgs` is unnecessary.